# how can i use multiple swiper js with different shapes in one html page

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, swiper.js

how can I use different swiper js in one html page. I have two different swiper js not the the same shapes  but different shapes for each. I need to use it in one html page i created one swiper and its working fine. but when I am add the second, it doesn't work.

Any help will be great.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  effect: "flip",
  grabCursor: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
});
//swiper 2
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper1", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  freeMode: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination_",
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50em;
  padding: 50px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10em;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  top: 42em;
}

.swiper1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide1 .img1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<header class="nav">
  <ul class="nav_">
    <li h><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="curve">
</div>
<section>
  <!-- <div class="section_header">
           
        </div> -->
  <img id="img_header" src="/img/Header_2.png" alt="">
</section>
<div class="section_title">
  <h3 id="section_products">Products</h3>
</div>
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <a href=""> <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      <h1 id="section_Name">مختار</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>

<!-- new Swiper -->
<div class="swiper mySwiper1">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide1">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide1">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide1">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide1">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide1">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide1">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide1">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide1">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide1">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination_"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Protip: You don't need those vendor prefixes for flexbox properties. Just use the [modern ones](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: You've named both Swiper instances the same thing. The second overwrites the first. Don't do that. :)